# Json to csv using jq or any other bash command

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have to parse a big json file to csv in as little a time as possible. I have the following sample json file:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "candles": [
            ["2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530", 1386.4, 1388, 1381.05, 1385.1, 788],
            ["2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530", 1385.1, 1389.1, 1383.85, 1385.5, 609],
            ["2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530", 1385.5, 1387, 1385.5, 1385.7, 212],
            ["2015-12-28T09:18:00+0530", 1387, 1387.95, 1385.3, 1387.95, 1208],
            ["2015-12-28T09:19:00+0530", 1387, 1387.55, 1385.6, 1386.25, 716],
            ["2015-12-28T09:20:00+0530", 1386.95, 1389.95, 1386.95, 1389, 727],
            ["2015-12-28T09:21:00+0530", 1389, 1392.95, 1389, 1392.95, 291],
            ["2015-12-28T09:22:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.95, 180],
            ["2015-12-28T09:23:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.15, 1869],
            ["2016-01-01T13:22:00+0530", 1386.4, 1388, 1381.05, 1385.1, 788],
            ["2016-01-01T13:23:00+0530", 1385.1, 1389.1, 1383.85, 1385.5, 613],
            ["2016-01-01T13:24:00+0530", 1385.5, 1387, 1385.5, 1385.7, 212],
            ["2016-01-01T13:25:00+0530", 1387, 1387.95, 1385.3, 1387.95, 1208],
            ["2016-01-01T13:26:00+0530", 1387, 1387.55, 1385.6, 1386.25, 716],
            ["2016-01-01T13:27:00+0530", 1386.95, 1389.95, 1386.95, 1389, 727],
            ["2016-01-01T13:28:00+0530", 1389, 1392.95, 1389, 1392.95, 291],
            ["2016-01-01T13:29:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.95, 180],
            ["2016-01-01T13:30:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.15, 1869]
        ]
    }
}
```

The data in the above file (say data.json) has to filtered and the candles data has to be saved in csv file (say output.csv). I am unable to get .data.candles data in a csv file. Output expected is:

```
2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530,1386.4,1388.0,1381.05,1385.1,788
2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530,1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,609
2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530,1385.5,1387.0,1385.5,1385.7,212
2015-12-28T09:18:00+0530,1387.0,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
2015-12-28T09:19:00+0530,1387.0,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
2015-12-28T09:20:00+0530,1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389.0,727
2015-12-28T09:21:00+0530,1389.0,1392.95,1389.0,1392.95,291
2015-12-28T09:22:00+0530,1392.95,1393.0,1392.0,1392.95,180
2015-12-28T09:23:00+0530,1392.95,1393.0,1392.0,1392.15,1869
2016-01-01T13:22:00+0530,1386.4,1388.0,1381.05,1385.1,788
2016-01-01T13:23:00+0530,1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,613
2016-01-01T13:24:00+0530,1385.5,1387.0,1385.5,1385.7,212
2016-01-01T13:25:00+0530,1387.0,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
2016-01-01T13:26:00+0530,1387.0,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
2016-01-01T13:27:00+0530,1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389.0,727
2016-01-01T13:28:00+0530,1389.0,1392.95,1389.0,1392.95,291
2016-01-01T13:29:00+0530,1392.95,1393.0,1392.0,1392.95,180
2016-01-01T13:30:00+0530,1392.95,1393.0,1392.0,1392.15,1869
```

I can do it in python, but owing to speed, I have to do it via jq.

A little help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
$ jq -r '.data.candles[] | @csv' data.json
"2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530",1386.4,1388,1381.05,1385.1,788
"2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530",1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,609
"2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530",1385.5,1387,1385.5,1385.7,212
"2015-12-28T09:18:00+0530",1387,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
"2015-12-28T09:19:00+0530",1387,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
"2015-12-28T09:20:00+0530",1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389,727
"2015-12-28T09:21:00+0530",1389,1392.95,1389,1392.95,291
"2015-12-28T09:22:00+0530",1392.95,1393,1392,1392.95,180
"2015-12-28T09:23:00+0530",1392.95,1393,1392,1392.15,1869
"2016-01-01T13:22:00+0530",1386.4,1388,1381.05,1385.1,788
"2016-01-01T13:23:00+0530",1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,613
"2016-01-01T13:24:00+0530",1385.5,1387,1385.5,1385.7,212
"2016-01-01T13:25:00+0530",1387,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
"2016-01-01T13:26:00+0530",1387,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
"2016-01-01T13:27:00+0530",1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389,727
"2016-01-01T13:28:00+0530",1389,1392.95,1389,1392.95,291
"2016-01-01T13:29:00+0530",1392.95,1393,1392,1392.95,180
"2016-01-01T13:30:00+0530",1392.95,1393,1392,1392.15,1869
```

It just sends all the elements of the candles array to the `@csv` output formatter, one at a time, and prints out the raw results instead of treating each output line as a JSON string (The `-r` option).

To save results in a file in a script, just use output redirection like normal:

```
jq -r '.data.candles[] | @csv' data.json > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to parse a big json file to csv in as little a time as
>   possible.

If the file is of the format you show, you may find a simple `sed` command much faster than `jq`. And, since the resulting format is .csv and not .json, then any json validations provide by `jq` would not be applicable here. An example of using `sed` for this is:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\s*[[]\([^]]*\).*$/\1/;s/"//g;s/,\s/,/gp' sample.json
2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530,1386.4,1388,1381.05,1385.1,788
2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530,1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,609
2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530,1385.5,1387,1385.5,1385.7,212
2015-12-28T09:18:00+0530,1387,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
2015-12-28T09:19:00+0530,1387,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
2015-12-28T09:20:00+0530,1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389,727
2015-12-28T09:21:00+0530,1389,1392.95,1389,1392.95,291
2015-12-28T09:22:00+0530,1392.95,1393,1392,1392.95,180
2015-12-28T09:23:00+0530,1392.95,1393,1392,1392.15,1869
2016-01-01T13:22:00+0530,1386.4,1388,1381.05,1385.1,788
2016-01-01T13:23:00+0530,1385.1,1389.1,1383.85,1385.5,613
2016-01-01T13:24:00+0530,1385.5,1387,1385.5,1385.7,212
2016-01-01T13:25:00+0530,1387,1387.95,1385.3,1387.95,1208
2016-01-01T13:26:00+0530,1387,1387.55,1385.6,1386.25,716
2016-01-01T13:27:00+0530,1386.95,1389.95,1386.95,1389,727
2016-01-01T13:28:00+0530,1389,1392.95,1389,1392.95,291
2016-01-01T13:29:00+0530,1392.95,1393,1392,1392.95,180
2016-01-01T13:30:00+0530,1392.95,1393,1392,1392.15,1869
```

`sed` being a pure stream-editor you may find it an order of magnitude faster than the equivalent operation using `jq`. Further, the `jq` solution in the other answer fails to remove the double-quotation marks around the date and time field. Give it a try...